# Selecting sample size for rare events

Tags: probability, statistics

Assuming a total population of $m$, where $m$ is 1 000 000, in this case products, and a null hypothesis
$H_0$ : $p$ = 0.0002 of a rare event $A$ and  $H_a$ : $p$ < 0.0002, how is it possible to select sample size $n$ to prove $H_a$ with confidence interval of 95%? Distribution is not known, but events can be considered to happen randomly among $m$ over the lifetime.

And vice-versa, given a sample size $n$ with occurrences of $A$, how is it possible to determine if the result is statistically significant?

Comment: The first half amounts to a power calculation.  You will need a specific value for $H_a$ to do this: the sample will be much smaller for $p=0.00001$ than for $p=0.00019$